# How to declarate control and state variables?

Tags: python, optimization, gekko

Good afernoon community, recently someone recommends me GEKKO library to do dynamic optimization through python. I'm trying to replicate this [paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0360544214000759#!) with that. Basically the model is:

[image: Energy Eficiency model]

According to the paper *E* is control variable and *K* is a state variable, the rest are constant values. I think my error is when I define *E* as a control variable, because when I do the output is that GEKKO can't find a solution. That's is the reason that belows I define as a parameter.

```
# Initialize GEKKO
m = GEKKO()

# Define values:
# Constant values
beta_1, beta_2, gamma, delta, s, alpha, L_bar = 0.2, 0.8, 0.5, 0.05, 0.4719, 10, 900000000
# Time period 
n = 100
t = np.linspace(0, 15, n) 
m.time = t

# Set initial conditions:
# Define K(0) = K_0 initial capital 
K = m.Var(value = 0)

# Restrictions problem:
# Define constraints
import math    
E = m.Param(-4 * (np.exp(t/2) - np.exp(-1))) # Control variable E
Y = m.Param((1 - gamma) * (K**beta_1) * (L_bar**(beta_2)) + gamma * E)
K_dot = m.SV(1, lb = 0, ub = 1)

m.Equation(K_dot.dt() == s * (Y - E) - delta * K)


J = m.Var(value = 0)                        
Jf = m.FV()                                 
Jf.STATUS = 1
# Define objective function :
m.Connection(Jf,J,pos2='end')
m.Equation(J.dt() == -1 *(E**2) - alpha * K_dot)
# Set solving options
m.Obj(-Jf) # maximize profit
# Set solving options
m.options.IMODE = 6  # optimal control
m.options.NODES = 3  # collocation nodes
m.options.SOLVER = 3 # solver (IPOPT)
# Solve maximization problem
m.solve(disp = False) # Solve

plt.plot(t, K, "--r")
```

Taking a look to the documentation, I think my problem is a mix between the "*load following*" exmple and the "*optimal control with economic objective*". In order to know if I did in the right way, I use figure 5 and 6 as reference. For the figure 5 when x = 11 there is change in the graphic...but for me it isn't. While in figure 6, the y axis is from [0, -3k] and according to my script is from [0, -7k].

Answer (score 0):

The decision variable `E` should be an `MV()` type and the `Y` variable should be an `Intermediate` type.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np

# Initialize GEKKO
m = GEKKO()

# Define values:
# Constant values
beta_1, beta_2 = 0.2, 0.8
gamma, delta, s, alpha, L_bar = 0.5, 0.05, 0.4719, 10, 900000000
# Time period 
n = 100
t = np.linspace(0, 15, n) 
m.time = t

# Set initial conditions:
# Define K(0) = K_0 initial capital 
K_0 = 0.1
K = m.Var(K_0)

# Restrictions problem:
# Define constraints
E = m.MV(lb=0.1,ub=0.2); E.STATUS=1 # Variable E is adjusted to Maximize objective
Y = m.Intermediate((1-gamma) * (K**beta_1) * (L_bar**(beta_2)) + gamma*E)
m.Equation(K.dt() == s * (Y-E) - delta*K)
p = np.zeros(n); p[-1]=1; final=m.Param(p)
m.Maximize(final*m.integral(-1 *(E**2) - alpha*K)) # maximize profit
# Set solving options
m.options.IMODE = 6  # optimal control
m.options.NODES = 3  # collocation nodes
m.options.SOLVER = 1 # solver (IPOPT)
m.options.MAX_ITER=1000
# Solve maximization problem
m.solve(disp = True) # Solve

plt.plot(t, K, "--r")
plt.show()
```

You will need to find the correct value of `K_0` from the paper and fill in any additional information such as the correct bounds on `E`. The solution currently appears unbounded (profit as a negative of the minimization increases with each solver iteration, up to 1000).

```
  995 -1.11943E+06  9.76562E-04
  996 -1.12056E+06  9.76562E-04
  997 -1.12168E+06  9.76562E-04
  998 -1.12281E+06  9.76562E-04
  999 -1.12393E+06  9.76562E-04
 
 Iter    Objective  Convergence
 1000 -1.12506E+06  9.76562E-04
 Maximum iterations
 
 ---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  APOPT (v1.0)
 Solution time  :    11.9291999999987      sec
 Objective      :   -1125059.40772567     
 Unsuccessful with error code            0
 ---------------------------------------------------
```

There are a few additional dynamic optimization problem examples that can help:

1. [Basic Examples](https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/DynamicOptimizationBenchmarks)
2. [More Advanced Examples](https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/MoreDynamicOptimizationBenchmarks)
3. [Energy Systems](https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/EnergyBenchmarks)

The [commercial fishery example](https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/EconomicDynamicOptimization) may be the closest application to the one you are solving.